# Disappearing transformations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, phantomjs

I'm having an odd problem with phantomJS somehow losing the transformations applied to some images. I have a webpage and in that webpage I have a function that takes some html and pastes it into the page. It looks something like this:

```
function RenderRaw(html, id) {
    elem = $("#raw");
    elem.html(html);
}
```

Now in the html I'm passing I have some images that look something like this:

```
<img id="map_layer0_tile_5_1_1" class="layerTile" style="width: 256px;
 height: 256px; visibility: visible; transform: translate(89px, -13px);" src="tile/5/11/5">
```

Now in my browser, this works fine. I can load the page, run the function passing in some html with images with transformations applied and they all appear in the right place. I did some debugging by looking at the image load event (where `debugDiv` is just a regular div somewhere else on the page):

```
var imgs = elem.find("img");
imgs.on('load', function(e) {
    var off = $(e.target).offset();
    var p = $("<p>").text(e.target.outerHTML);
    debugDiv.append(p);
    debugDiv.append("<p>" + e.target.style.transform + "</p>");
    debugDiv.append("<p>" + e.target.style.width + ", " + e.target.style.height + "</p>");
    debugDiv.append("<p>" + e.target.src + ": top=" + off.top + ", left=" + off.left + "</p>");
}
```

And I see exactly what I expect, in particular, I see

```
translate(89px, -13px)
```

Where I get the `transform` property of `style` and the `off.top` and `off.left` are what I expect them to be.

However, when I run this through phantomJS, it appears that the `transform` is getting stripped out. The `outerHTML` looks exactly as before, but my line accessing `style.transform` returns:

```
undefined
```

Not that the `style.width` and `style.height` can both still be accessed as expected. And now, without the transform being applied, my image is not correctly positioned.

Does anybody have any idea what might be happening here? Where'd my `transform` go?

EDIT:

Looking more closely, it looks like if I `JSON.stringify` the `style` object in phantom I can see it has no `transform` property, but it does have `webkitTransform`. So I guess phantomJS doesn't support `transform`?

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you use? (Have you tried PhantomJS 2?) It is possible that PhantomJS somehow fails to re-evaluate the CSS (try to do it yourself maybe with `document.body.style.zoom=document.body.style.zoom;`).

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm running 2.0.0.0

Comment: @ArtjomB. The `document.body.style.zoom` trick doesn't seem to do anything to force it to reevaluate. Forcing it to reevaluate seems like a good idea however.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the problem is that phantomJS 2.0 doesn't support `transform` at all. It's not mentioned in the [release notes](http://phantomjs.org/release-2.0.html) unfortunately. To work around this, I did this in the load event for each image:

```
var thisImg = $(e.target);
if (e.target.style.transform === undefined && e.target.style.webkitTransform !== undefined) {
    var style = thisImg.attr("style");
    style += "-webkit-transform: " + /transform:([^;]*;)/.exec(style)[1];
    thisImg.attr("style", style);
}
```

Basically extracting the `transform` and copying it to the `-webkit-transform`.